# Dplyr: compute features on the last X rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to compute some features:

- By User_id
- On a rolling window of 2 rows *(current row and previous row)*

I have this:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  user_id = rep(1:2, each=4),
  question = c("yes", "yes", "no",  "no","yes", "no", "yes", "no")
)
```

I'd like to get this:

```
Data2 <- data.frame(
  Data,
  nb_yes_last_2rows = c(1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
)
```

**Explanation:**

1. from the 1st row point of view, the current
   row and the previous row (which doesn't exist) contain 1 "yes".
2. from the 2nd row pov, the current row and the previous row contain 2 "yes"
3. from the 3rd row pov, the current row and the previous row contain 1 "yes"
4. from the 4th row pov, the current row and the previous row contain 0 "yes"
5. Warning: it concerns a new user, so I don't take into account the previous row which concerns another user.
   from the 1st row point of view, the current row and the previous row (which doesn't exist for this user) contain 1 "yes".
6. ...

**Question:**

How can I compute the `nb_yes_last_2rows` column of the 2nd data set in a `dplyr` way ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Have a look a the package vignette [*Introduction to dplyr*](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)

Comment: I've clarified the question.

Comment: You want to put `1` everywhere, and count only if there are more than 1 consecutive "yes"?

Comment: @Jaap I'm already familliar with this vignette but I didn't find the answer to this problem.

Comment: @DavidArenburg There was a mistake in my example I fixed it. 0 could happen if the current row is a 'no' and the previous one is also a 'no'

Comment: So I don't get the "no" logic. What happens if there are 3 "no" or "yes" in a row?

Comment: I'm not couting the number of "no" or "yes" in a row but  couting for each user, the number of yes in the current and the previous row.
Which row doesn't seem ok to you ?

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you looking for. You are basically want to count the instances of "yes" in a rolling window of 2

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

Data %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(nb_yes_last_2rows = rollapply(question, 2, function(x) sum(x == "yes"), 
                                       partial = TRUE, align = "right"))

# Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
# Groups: user_id
# 
#   user_id question nb_yes_last_2rows
# 1       1      yes                 1
# 2       1      yes                 2
# 3       1       no                 1
# 4       1       no                 0
# 5       2      yes                 1
# 6       2       no                 1
# 7       2      yes                 1
# 8       2       no                 1
```

Comment: Yes I thinks this is what I want. I should have used the term rolling window instead of specific window. Thanks